# how can I use a variable's value that is in a function i want to use that in another function

Tags: python, function, variables

```
def function1():  
    hi = "hello mom"

def function2():
    text = hi
```

#i want to import hi's value here in text from function1() sorry for the indentation I'm new here

Comment: use globals in python

Comment: You simply cannot do that.  `hi`, as a local variable, only exists during a call to `function1()`; the function doesn't do anything during that time to make the variable available elsewhere (such as returning it, or assigning it to a global variable), so the value simply vanishes.

Comment: @Himanshuman. Please don't

Comment: @jasonharper. That's what return values are for....

Comment: i need an explanation please 